# Perspective Transform (Homography) on rgb-d images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, depth, homography

I'm using a RGB-D camera (Intel Realsense D345) to implement a table top projected augmented reality system. Using chessboard calibration I obtain a transformation matrix which I use to transform each incoming frame using warpPerspective from openCV. It works really well for the color frames. The problem is, am I allowed to do this for depth images as well ? Considering depth images are 3D geometrical data. What's the right way to apply a transformation matrix to depth images?

Comment: did you find a solution? can you answer your question

Comment: I didn't, I ended up applying the same technique as for RGB images, it worked pretty well but was probably less accurate than it could have been