# Orthographic Projection in OpenCV for Projecting 3D Points

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, projection, orthographic

I have the following inputs:

- A color image of size 480 x 848 pixels
- An aligned depth image of size 480 x 848 pixels
- Camera intrinsic parameters
- A transformation from the camera to my frame located at the top

Consider the camera looking into an object from an angle. Furthermore, assume that we have defined a frame at the top of this object. **I want to transform the color and depth image from the camera to this frame. As if the camera is mounted at this frame.**

The 3D points (a point cloud having x, y, and z values without color)  can be obtained using depth image and camera parameters. I want to transform these 3D points (with color) into the top frame. Because these 3D points are actual points in a 3D space, I believe this is just an orthographic projection.

### Sample Code

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import cv2 as cv
In [3]: cv.__version__
Out[3]: '4.2.0'

In [4]: image = cv.imread("image.png")
In [5]: image.shape, image.dtype
Out[5]: ((480, 848, 3), dtype('uint8'))

In [6]: depth = cv.imread("depth.png", cv.CV_16UC1)
In [7]: depth.shape, depth.dtype
Out[7]: ((480, 848), dtype('uint16'))

In [8]: mask = np.ones_like(depth) * 255
In [9]: mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
In [10]: mask.shape, mask.dtype
Out[10]: ((480, 848), dtype('uint8'))

In [11]: # define transformation from camera to my frame located at top
In [12]: Rt = np.array([[ 1. , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.    ],
    ...:                [ 0. ,  0.89867918,  0.43860659, -0.191 ],
    ...:                [-0. , -0.43860659,  0.89867918,  0.066 ],
    ...:                [ 0. ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.    ]])

In [13]: # camera focal lengths and principal point
In [14]: cameraMatrix = np.array([[ 428.12915039,           0, 418.72729492 ],
    ...:                          [            0, 427.6109314, 238.20678711 ],
    ...:                          [            0,           0,            1 ]])

In [15]: # camera distortion parameters (k1, k2, t1, t2, k3)
In [16]: distCoeff = np.array([-0.05380916, 0.0613398, -0.00064336, 0.00040269, -0.01984365])

In [17]: warpedImage, warpedDepth, warpedMask = cv.rgbd.warpFrame(image, depth, mask, Rt, cameraMatrix, distCoeff)
In [18]: cv.imwrite("warpedImage.png", warpedImage)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: cv.imwrite("warpedDepth.png", warpedDepth)
Out[19]: True
```

### Frame Visualization

- The camera is located at camera_color_optical_frame and looking at the object at an angle
- The top frame named my_frame is situated on the top of the object
- The object is kept at workspace frame

[image: Frame Visualization]

### Input Images

- Color Image[image: Color Image]
- Depth Image[image: Depth Image]

### Output Images

- Warped Image[image: Warped Image]
- Warped Depth[image: Warped Depth]

### Expected Output

The output image should be similar to the picture taken from the camera at the top position. A sample image is shown below. We know that we can not get precisely this image; nevertheless, the image below is just for reference purposes.

[image: Expected Output]

Notice carefully that this image does not contain the red color attached to the object's walls.

Comment: you can see that the rotation appears to have happened *away from* your desired orientation... perhaps you've got some transformation the wrong way.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: Thanks for the comment. I checked the implementation of the [warpFrame](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/65abc7090dedc84bbedec4dfd143f0340e52114f/modules/rgbd/src/odometry.cpp#L924-L974) function. It turned out that perspective transform is used inside that takes the input transformation, i.e., `Rt`. However, I need orthographic transform. Another thiing, I noticed is that if `Rt` is an identity matrix, then the generated view is matching with input image.

Comment: you should maybe invert `Rt`, depending on how that thing is defined. -- don't jump to conclusions. just because an api call to "perspective"-anything exists, doesn't mean there's actually any perspective mapping happening. that's just the function to multiply by a 3x3 or 4x4 matrix. if that matrix happens to contain a perspective transform, it'll be applied. of not, then not. the api call transforms the point cloud, as it should. don't confuse yourself.

Comment: just to be clear: 1- you have an image of an object.  2- then you are capturing the same object from different perspectives with a depth camera 3- you want to transfer depth points/data of this object to the image taken at the beginning, you want to match with that ? Am I correct ? If yes whats the purpose of this system design

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk the goal seems to be creating a top-down view of the 3D scan... which is absolutely sensible and doable. OP is just confused about the direction of some transformation matrices.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk: Sorry for the confusion. Christoph Rackwitz summarized it well. I am not capturing the same object from different perspectives with a depth camera. Instead the objected is viewed (captured a set of RGB and Depth images) from an angle. I want to compose new color and depth images, that should look as if the camera was looking exactly down (top down view).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: I think the inverse is giving better results. I would like to share them here for your reference. Please see [warpedImage.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4fj5i1qlgv66cp/warpedImageRtInv.png?dl=0) and [warpedDepth.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpg6omdp7309s1s/warpedDepthRtInv.png?dl=0). You may notice a bit of red color in the picture. Now, I guess that the frame is not exactly vertical. What are your suggestions, please?

Comment: you should investigate why these point clouds are so blobby. I'd expect sharper edges on objects, not these rounded blobby edges. -- allowing for some misalignment between depth and color data (the red front of the box spilling onto the sides and everything else), this looks like the transformation was successful.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: Thanks a lot. The environment was very bright while capturing images. For example, you can see the top left side of the input color image to verify the brightness level. The generated point cloud (by using Intel's API) is also not smooth. I am going to check the camera calibration and stop overexposing the light. Thanks again. For now, the question asked above is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are fine with blank space due to parts not seen in the image, using another package, and some extra processing time, you can use Open3D to transform(basically, rotate) the RGBD Image by the required amount.

First create a open3d [RGBD-image](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/rgbd_image.html)

```
import open3d as o3d
color_raw = o3d.io.read_image("image.png")
depth_raw = o3d.io.read_image("depth.png")
rgbd_image = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(
    color_raw, depth_raw)
```

Then, convert to PCD, (I tried transforming an RGBD image but didn't work.. so conversion)

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(
rgbd_image,
o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic(
    o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsicParameters.PrimeSenseDefault))
# Flip it, otherwise the pointcloud will be upside down
pcd.transform([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd], zoom=0.5)
```

Replace the default camera parameters by your own.

Then, you can use a [transformation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/transformation.html) according to the frames

Next, if you have to convert the pcd back to an RGBD image, follow [this example](https://github.com/pablospe/render_depthmap_example).

Secondly, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655995/perspective-transform-homography-on-rgb-d-images) is a similar unanswered question where the user ends up using perspective transform for 2-D images

PS. new here, suggestions welcome

Comment: also, your depth image looks bad.. check if your camera is well calibrated/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate it. Unfortunately, I am not looking for a third-party library. I believe OpenCV is powerful enough to handle this case! Thanks for your review of the depth image. It is given here as a means to complete the question. I am noting down your point on camera calibration as well.